# JSON.net (newtonsoft) - Access deep 'property' C#

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, json.net

I am using the great NewtonSoft.Json library on Windows Phone 7.1 (mango).

I would like to access a deep property (red arrow) on a Bing json answer:

[image: Bing json answer]

I have assigned the answered string on `resultado` variable and I have tried to do on this way:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(resultado);
JsonAddress unaAddress = 
       JsonConvert
       .DeserializeObject<JsonAddress>(o["resourceSets"][0]["resources"][0].ToString());
MessageBox.Show(unaAddress.Coordinates.X);  // iexample..
```

But I don't know how to define the class `JsonAddress` to get the info I need.

```
public class JsonAddress
{
    // public xxxx Coordinates { get; set; }
}
```

Any help ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it:

Defining the class (and a child class) in this way:

```
public class JsonAddress
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public JsonPoint Point { get; set; }

}
public class JsonPoint
{
    public double[] Coordinates { get; set; }
}
```

And accesing it in this way:

```
MessageBox.Show(unaAddress.Point.Coordinates[0] + ", " +
                unaAddress.Point.Coordinates[1]);
```

Thanks and sorry by your wasted time... :-\